# Uniswap v2 getAmountsOut price for fractional value tokens

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js, web3py, uniswap

I want to get price of tokens like [CAW](https://v2.info.uniswap.org/pair/0x48d20b3e529fb3dd7d91293f80638df582ab2daa), [SHINJA](https://v2.info.uniswap.org/pair/0x63b61e73d3fa1fb96d51ce457cabe89fffa7a1f1), etc on blockchain and not using uniswap subgraph api.

```
router_contract_obj = w3.eth.contract(
   address=Web3.toChecksumAddress(IUNISWAP_V2_ROUTER),
   abi=router_contract_abi
)

prices = await router_contract_obj.functions.getAmountsOut(
   10 ** int(token_metadata['decimals']), 
   [
      Web3.toChecksumAddress(token_metadata['address']),
      Web3.toChecksumAddress(WETH)
   ]
).call()

token_eth_price = token_eth_price[1]/10**tokens_decimals["WETH"]
```

above code works with any major coin like WBTC, DAI, USDC, etc..

But when I try this for tokens like `CAW` I get 0 as its eth value. This is probably due to very low price of these tokens: e.g. from uniswap transaction page I can see for `6.07 billion CAW` is swapped for `589.3763 USDC`.

I tried increasing input amount in `getAmountsOut` function and got the non zero value but it is not correct.

```
router_contract_obj = w3.eth.contract(
   address=Web3.toChecksumAddress(IUNISWAP_V2_ROUTER),
   abi=router_contract_abi
)

prices = await router_contract_obj.functions.getAmountsOut(
   1000000000 * 10 ** int(token_metadata['decimals']), 
   [
      Web3.toChecksumAddress(token_metadata['address']),
      Web3.toChecksumAddress(WETH)
   ]
).call()

token_eth_price = token_eth_price[1]/1000000000
token_eth_price = token_eth_price/10**tokens_decimals["WETH"]
```

output: `token_eth_price = 8.474e-24`

Am I doing something wrong or is there any other way for this?